# NGINX serve different paths from different locations

Tags: nginx

I have poked around in all similar topics and can't seem to cut through this one.

My set up: 2 different JS apps served through their index.html files:

*/var/www/html/original_dir/dist -> served from my.awesomesite.com*

*/var/www/html/not_so_original_dir/dist -> served from my.awesomesite.com/oldie*

```
server {
  root /var/www/html/original_dir/dist;
  index index.html;
  server_name my.awesomesite.com;
  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
  }
}
```

I guess using an alias could solve this.

```
server {
  root /var/www/html/original_dir/dist;
  index index.html;
  server_name my.awesomesite.com;
  location /oldie {
    alias /var/www/html/not_so_original_dir/dist;
    index index.html;
  }
}
```

When my.awesomesite.com/oldie is accessed the correct index.html is requested however all css and js references are resolved with old location:
Fx a reference for /css/app.css at my.awesomesite.com/oldie is attempting to be resolved at /var/www/html/original_dir/dist/css/app.css instead of /var/www/html/not_so_original_dir/dist/css/app.css.

Any idea on how to fix the files so to be delivered through the correct folder?

Comment: Did you try a "./css/app.css" reference?

Comment: Please add the complete nginx configuration as given by `nginx -T` command to the question.